# Why is the Acceptance-Rejection Sampling Algorithm able to produce samples from the target distribution?

Tags: probability

I am trying to understand why is the Acceptance-Rejection Sampling Algorithm able to produce samples from the target distribution. I have seen several explanations for this, but have never been able to fully grasp the concept. Thus, I spent the past few days trying to come up with an explanation that made sense to me and is also logical/factually correct.

As a recap, here is the Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm:

- A) Generate a sample $x$ from a proposal distribution that has a density proportional to a function $g(x)$, where $g(x) \geq f(x)$ for all $x$. Here, $f(x)$ is the density of the target distribution.
- B) Generate a uniform random number $u$ between 0 and 1.
- C) If $u > \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, reject the sample $x$ and return to A); otherwise, accept $x$ as a sample from the target distribution.

Now, I will attempt to write a derivation of the Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm myself.

**Step 1:** Suppose we want to obtain samples from a complex distribution $f(x)$, this is will be the target distribution. However, this is not possible. So instead, we can cleverly use another distribution called $g(x)$ to strategically take samples from $f(x)$. We will call $g(x)$ as the proposal distribution. $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have to be chosen in such a way, such that for some constant $c$:

$$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \leq c$$
$$\frac{f(x)}{c \cdot g(x)} \leq 1$$

**Step 2:** Now, let's denote a random variable $U$ such that:

$$P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}] = \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}$$

Notice that this equivalence is only true in the case of a Uniform Distribution:

$$P[U \leq a] = a$$

**Step 3:** Suppose we simulate a random number from $g(y)$. Now, we can find out the Expected Value of $\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}$:

$$E\left[\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}\right] = \int_y \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} g(y) dy$$

$$= \int_y \frac{1}{c} f(y) dy$$

$$= \frac{1}{c}$$

From a different perspective, if we generate some random number $x$ from $g(x)$ and become interested in the probability that $U \leq \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}$, we can also write:

$$P(U \leq \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}) = \int \left(U \leq \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}\right) g(x) \, dx = 
\int \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)} g(x) \, dx$$

$$P(U \leq \frac{f(x)}{cg(x)}) = \frac{1}{c}$$

**Step 4:**  Using the following formulation of Bayes Law:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$$
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A|B)P(B)$$
$$P(B \cap A) = P(B|A)P(A)$$

Since:
$$P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A) $$

Then:

$$P(B|A)P(A) = P(A|B)P(B)$$
$$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$$

**Step 5:** In general, we know that the Acceptance-Rejection Algorithm works as follows. If we simulate a random number $y$ from $g(y)$  ... provided that if a $U=u \sim(0,1)$  is less than equal to $\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}$, then we can accept that $y$ has come from the CDF $F(y)$:

$$P[Y \leq y | U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}] = F(y)$$

Using the formulation of Bayes Law $P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A) P(A)}{P(B)}$, we can write $P[Y \leq y | U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}]$ as:

$$P[Y \leq y | U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}] = \frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y=y] * P[Y \leq y]}{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}]}$$

Analyzing the above expression, we can observe that:

- From Step 3, we know that the denominator of the above term is : $P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}] = \frac{1}{c}$ . Note that this is again a Uniform CDF.
- And since $y$ is a random number from a random variable $Y$, and since $Y$ has probability distribution $g(Y)$, this means that the second term in the numerator can be expressed relative to the CDF: $P[Y \leq y] = G(Y)$

**Step 6:** Now, looking at the first term in the numerator $P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y\leq y]$, we use the relationship $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ to re-write::

$$P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y\leq y] = \frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}, Y\leq y]}{P[Y \leq y]} = \frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}, Y\leq y]}{G(Y)}$$

Again, relying on the fact that $P(A|B)P(B) = P(A \cap B)$ , I can transform the joint distribution in the numerator $\frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}, Y\leq y]}{G(Y)}$ back into a conditional distribution by multiplying it by the distribution of $Y$:

$$P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y\leq y] = \frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}| Y\leq y] * g(Y)}{G(Y)}$$

Now, we can integrate the right hand side since the left hand side is telling us that we are interested in the probability $Y\leq y$:

$$P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y\leq y] = \int \frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}| Y\leq y] * g(Y)}{G(Y)} dY$$

Relying on the fact that in general:

$$\int_{d}^{c} \frac{f(x)}{\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx} = \frac{1}{\int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx} \int_{d}^{c} f(x) dx$$

And for the Uniform Distribution (**Step 2**):

$$P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y\leq y] = \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}$$

We can resume writing:

$$\frac{1}{cG(y)} \int_{-\infty}^{y} \left[\frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}\right] g(y) dy = \frac{1}{cG(y)} \int_{-\infty}^{y} f(y) dy = \frac{F(y)}{cG(y)}$$

**Step 7:** We can resume writing the expression from **Step 5** as:

$$P[Y \leq y | U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}] = \frac{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)} | Y=y] * P[Y \leq y]}{P[U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}]} =  \frac{\frac{F(y)}{cG(Y)} \cdot G(y)}{\frac{1}{c}} = \frac{\frac{F(y)}{c}}{\frac{1}{c}} = F(y)$$

Thus, we have shown that :

- if you are able to generate a random number $y$ from some distribution $g(y)$
- a random number from $U \sim (0,1)$
- if the condition $U \leq \frac{f(y)}{cg(y)}$ is met , then we can believe that $y$ also belongs to the CDF $F(Y)$

This means that we can simulate random numbers from some complex distribution $f(y)$ (since the PDF and CDF have the same support) without directly simulating from $f(y)$, thus concluding the proof.

Is my analysis correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is very eloquent and correct. However, for enlightenment and expanding your horizons regarding computation, my belief is that the rejection method is much less efficient than the inverse cumulative method.

Assuming your $y=f(x)$ is continuous, differential, smooth, and monotonic, for rejection you first have to perform a random draw to get candidate $x$, and then draw a $U(0,1)$ to determine if it's less than $f(x)/cg(x)$. If not, you have to draw another $x$ and $U(0,1)$, since you can't simply sit at the randomly drawn $x$ and continue to make draws on $U(0,1)$ until $U(0,1)<f(x)/cg(x)$ -- you have to redraw another $x$ whenever $U(0,1) \geq f(x)/cg(x)$.

Enter the inverse cumulative method, where you run e.g. cubic splines on the cumulative function of $cdf(y)=x$.  Then, for each random draw from $U(0,1)$, you come in to the left $y$-axis whose range is [0,1], go over to the cubic spline fitted line, and then down to the $x$-axis to acquire the fitted $x$-value.  Many (statistical) software packages use this approach for simulation due to its efficiency.

Formally, $f(x)$ is the probability density function, and the cumulative function is called the distribution function, $F(x)$.  After running cubic splines on $F(x)$ vs $x$, you would be inputting random values of $U(0,1)$ into $F^{-1}(x)$ and then pulling out $x$ -- which is functionally composed as $x=F^{-1}(U(0,1))$.

**Note:** use of e.g. the cubic spline approach above is mostly for empirical datasets.  If you are dealing instead with known probability distributions, there are usually closed form analytic solutions (equations) and/or algorithms which yield $x=F^{-1}(U(0,1))$.  In such cases, these are called "percentage points" of a probability distribution.  For example, input 0.025 (a prob in range [0,1]), and you get $-1.96$ from the inverse cumulative normal function $\rightarrow -1.96=\Phi^{-1}(0.025)$ and $1.96=\Phi^{-1}(0.975)$.